# Box2d how to setAwake all the bodies in a world in the easiest way

Tags: libgdx, box2d

I wants all the bodies in the world to wake up at once when i trigger something (in my case is setting inverse gravity force to float all dynamic bodies upwards).

My current thinking is creating another Body arraylist to keep the bodies created and setAwake on each body using forLoop function.

Is there any easier way other than that?

Comment: Please provide code so that others can help you properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you add a body, add it to a list as well.
When you trigger, iterate through the list and set everything to awake.

If you do not want to manage your own list, you can use [this](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/World.html#getBodies-com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Array-) method in the World class as below:

```
Array<Body> bodies = new Array<>();
world.getBodies(array);
for (Body b : bodies) {
    b.setAwake();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your assist. I was trying to find a better way other than creating a new list for achieving this :)

Comment: I've added another method that you may prefer to my answer.

Comment: Thanks !! Thats what i am looking for! Never know this can be done this way.